# modify pandas boxplot output

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I made this plot in pandas, according to the documentation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(140, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['models'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['model1','model2', 'model3', 'model4', 'model5', 'model6', 'model7'], 20))
plt.figure()
bp = df.boxplot(by="models")
```

[image]

How can I modify this plot?

I want:

- modify arrangement from (2,2) to (1,4)
- change the labels and titles, text and font size
- remove the '[models]' text

and how do I save this plot as pdf ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For the arrangement use `layout`
- For setting x label use `set_xlabel('')`
- For figure title use `figure.subtitle()`
- For changing the figure size use `figsize=(w,h)` (inches)

note: the line `np.asarray(bp).reshape(-1)` is converting the layout of the subplots (2x2 for instance) to an array.

code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(140, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['models'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['model1','model2', 'model3', 'model4', 'model5', 'model6', 'model7'], 20))
bp = df.boxplot(by="models",layout=(4,1),figsize=(6,8))
[ax_tmp.set_xlabel('') for ax_tmp in np.asarray(bp).reshape(-1)]
fig = np.asarray(bp).reshape(-1)[0].get_figure()
fig.suptitle('New title here')
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

Comment: this does not work for me, i get `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel`

Comment: @spore234 comment the line `bp = df.boxplot(by="models",layout=(1,4))` and put a  `print bp` before or after it,  run the code and paste the result of the output here

Comment: I get this from print (shortened it): [[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f59e10c6630>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f59e002b5c0>

Comment: thanks, that works. Do you know how I can change the figsize?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126184/discussion-between-spore234-and-yugi).

Comment: What would be the parameter for changing the individual colors of the boxes in each subplot?

Answer (score 2):

A number of things you can do already using the boxplot function in pandas, see the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html).

- You can already modify the arrangement, and change the fontsize:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import pyplot as plt

  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(140, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
  df['models'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['model1','model2', 'model3', 'model4', 'model5', 'model6', 'model7'], 20))
  bp = df.boxplot(by="models", layout = (4,1), fontsize = 14)
  ```
- Changing the columns the labels can be done by changing the columns labels of the dataframe itself:

  ```
  df.columns(['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'models'])
  ```
- For further customization I would use the functionality from matlotlib itself; you can take a look at the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to change the individual boxplot labels (known as tick labels): `model1`,`model2`,etc they can be changed using the [set_xticklables](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)() function e.g. to rename the xtick labels to be mX:

```
ax=bp[-1].axes
ax.set_xticklabels([f"m{(n%7)+1}" for n in range(len(ax.get_xticklabels()))])
```