# How to color a boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRjMm.png)I mad a boxplot from a df (pets) with the type of animal and age of each animal. I need the cat box to be purple, dog to be green, and parrot to be orange. I can't figure out how to change the the color of the individual boxes.

I have been on stack all day trying different codes. Not sure in particular what I have tried though. I am relatively new to python.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as pl t
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    pets = pd.read_csv('pets (1).csv')
    boxplot = pets.boxplot(column=['Age'], by=['Kind'], patch_artist = True)
```

I have a boxplot that shows the 3 different animal kinds by age, but they are all filled in blue and need the colors to be different for each one.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297093/change-the-facecolor-of-boxplot-in-pandas). Using `seaborn` [boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) is super easy with `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of individual boxes in pandas boxplot subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963960/change-color-of-individual-boxes-in-pandas-boxplot-subplots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily in `seaborn`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette(['purple', 'green', 'orange'])
pets = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.rand(10), 'Kind': ['Cat']*3+['Dog']*3 + ['Parrot']*4})
sns.boxplot(x='Kind', y='Age', data = pets)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so simple now, but I do not have prior experience with seaborn.